# How to convert C string to X509_NAME

Tags: openssl, x509

How can I convert string/char* to X509_NAME* ?

```
const char* issuer_c = issuerstr.c_str();
X509_NAME* issuerName = d2i_X509_NAME(NULL, (const unsigned char**)&issuer_c, -1);
```

Issuer name is NULL even after call to `d2i_X509_NAME`.
I think this `d2i` method only works on binary data. So How can I convert string to X509_NAME?

Comment: Maybe [`X509_NAME_new`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_NAME_new.html)?

Comment: `X509_NAME_new` will return X509_NAME*. fine. But how to assign char* to it ? Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Check out [`X509_NAME *parse_name(...)`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/apps.c#L1718) in `apps.c`. Its an internal OpenSSL function, but it shows you how the library does it.

Comment: Thanks @jww. It helped. That is method is for subject name conversion. I hope it works for issuer name also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/X509_NAME_add_entry.html)

```
p_name = X509_NAME_new();
X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(p_name , ...)
/// cleanup ...
```